# How do I find the number of times elements of a list occur in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have two lists:

```
A=['a','b','c']
B=['a','a','b','c']
```

I want my output to look like:

```
[2,1,1]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
P=np.ndarray(shape=3, dtype=int)
count=0
d=0

for i in A:
  for j in B:
    if i==j:
        count+=1
        P[d]=count
d+=1
```

But I am getting

```
[2,3,4]
```

as output. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `count` method:

```
A=['a','b','c']
B=['a','a','b','c']

[B.count(x) for x in A]
```

Answer (score 3):

The methods as suggested by [@CarlesMitjans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565065/588071) or [@WillenVanOnsem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565080/588071) are better solutions than this, but the reason your method does not work is that you need to initialise your `count` variable inside the first loop (and also indent the `d+=1` line):

```
P = np.ndarray(shape=3, dtype=int)
count = 0
d = 0

for i in A:
    count = 0  
    for j in B:
        if i == j:
            count += 1
            P[d] = count
    d += 1
```

which gives:

```
>>> P
array([2, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

**If the elements are hashable**, you can simply **use a counter** you then transform back into a list. Like:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(B)
result = [ctr[x] for x in A]
```

This generates:

```
>>> [ctr[x] for x in A]
[2, 1, 1]
```

This works in *O(|A|+|B|)* with *|A|* the numbers in `A` and *|B|* the numbers in `B` (given dictionary lookup works in *O(1)*, which is nearly always the case).

If the elements **can not be hashed** (for instance `list`s, `dict`ionaries, `object`s,...), then you can use [@CharlesMitjans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565065/67579) answer, which runs in ***O(|A|×|B|)*** (which tends to be less efficient, but then you cannot take advantage of hashing).